# Convert a Java List<String> into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI autocomplete to show suggestions for a text input field.
The suggestions are stored in a Javascript array called suggestions.

I'm trying to fetch the string values for the suggestions array from a database, but I can't convert the List object to a Javascript array.

The Javascript:

```
var suggestions = [];
$.get('/mywebapp/autocompleteplayer.html', function(data){
    parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    suggestions = parsed.split(",");
}, "json");

$('#autocompleted').autocomplete({
    data: suggestions,
    minLength: 3
});
```

The Spring MVC controller:

```
@Controller
public class AutocompletePlayerController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/autocompleteplayer")
    public List<String> getPlayerSuggestions(){

        List<String> myList;
        //code that fills myList with all of the players' full names from the database, omitted for brevity
        return myList;
    }
}
```

I know I'm not parsing the AJAX response properly, since I've checked from the browser console that the suggestions array has 0 elements. Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried outputting the value of `data` in the browser console? If you give us the value of that, it will make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Maybe you should return a Response instead and write the entity in it. Or try @ResponseBody before your return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use it like this in your js (data is the response entity, not the data - it's in `data.data`) :

```
$.get('/mywebapp/autocompleteplayer', function(data){
    suggestions = data.data; 
    $('#autocompleted').autocomplete({ // not sure how to use your plugin
        data: suggestions,
        minLength: 3
    });
}, "json");
```

And in your spring controller, add the `@ResponseBody` Annotation

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/autocompleteplayer")
@ResponseBody
public List<String> getPlayerSuggestions(){

    List<String> myList;
    //code that fills myList with all of the players' full names from the database, omitted for brevity
    return myList;
}
```

There's no need to `JSON.parse` anything, jquery already did this.

`/mywebapp/autocompleteplayer.html` also sounds wrong. The route is `autocompleteplayer` without `.html`.

Other than that, suggestions is created async. So your data in autocomplete will always be empty. I didn't use that plugin myself so there might be an update function for the data, otherwise try to put it in the `$.get()` functions callback.

Comment: I followed your suggestions. Besides, I've modified the js like this: $('#autocompleted').autocomplete({
 data: $.get('/Fantacalc/autocompleteplayer.html', function(data){
  var suggestions = [];
  suggestions = data.data;
 }, "json"),
 minLength: 3
}); but I got a 406 error

Answer (score 1):

You can return json array as String in java

```
@Produces("application/json")
public String getPlayerSuggestions(){
....
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
 String jsonString = gson.toJson(myList);
 return jsonString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The JSON object is created as expected. Now I just need to find a way to bind it to the autocomplete widget.

Comment: add @Produces("application/json") to method. updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/autocompleteplayer", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getPlayerSuggestions(){

    List<String> myList;
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();


    for(String item: myList){

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("Item", item);
        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

    }

    return jsonArray.toString();
}
```

then you can handle your values easy with `JSON`.
Regards,